# Why is "static mutable int n;" not allowed in C++?

Tags: c++, static, declaration, semantics, mutable

```
struct A
{
    // clang 3.8 error : cannot combine with previous 'static' declaration specifier
    static mutable int n;
};
```

I think `static mutable int n;` has clear semantics in some cases. **Why is it not allowed in C++?**

**Update:**

Another example to show `clear semantics`:

```
class SharedValue
{
public:
    void Set(int n)
    {
        std::lock_guard lock(_mtx);
        _n = n;
    }


    int Get() const
    {
        std::lock_guard lock(_mtx);
        //
        // _mtx should be mutable, 
        // because this is in const member function
        //

        return _n;
    }

private:
    static mutable std::mutex _mtx;
    int _n;
};
```

Comment: _"has clear semantics in some cases"_ Can you please elaborate upon these? I Don't get what you mean. `static` has nothing to do with `const` or `mutable`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You said:

> ```
>    // _mtx must be mutable, because this is in const member function
> ```

That's a misunderstanding. A `static` member variable can be modified in a `const` member function since the former is not associated with a specific instance of the class. Hence, the notion of `mutable` for a `static` member variable does not make much sense.

Answer (score 4):

A `static` class member variable isn't bound to an instance of a class.
So `mutable` that would change behavior with accessing and changing values from a `const` class **instance** won't make any sense.

---

As for your example that you provided with your update:

> ```
>  // _mtx should be mutable, 
>  // because this is in const member function
> ```

The `std::mutex _mtx;` shouldn't be a `static` member. You don't need to lock *all instances* of `SharedValue` but the current one only (and even if not, you don't need provide `mutable` `_mtx` for a `static` member to be changeable, it already is).

Just omit the `static` keyword, using `mutable` mutexes is a common technique.

Answer (score 0):

There is no clear possible semantics because the standard doesn't support that combination of keywords.

In original C keywords generally had mnemonic value.

In current C++ keywords have been reused so that they have a variety of meanings, e.g. multiple meanings of `static` (which is one of your keywords).

---

Note that `const`-ness of a non-`static` member function is about the `const`-ness of `*this`, and has nothing to do with `const`-ness of a `static` data member.

If we were to define some not wholly unnatural meaning for `mutable` applied to a `static` data member, it would have to be in connection with `const` for `static` member functions. Which is another just possible language extension.

You can implement restrictions on mutability by defining a separate class to hold the `static` state.